# Property of type int doesn't reflect in UI when changed in code-behind in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, properties, inotifypropertychanged

This is my XAML code:

```
<Label x:Name="currentPage" Width="45" Height="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding CurrentPageNo, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

This is my code-behind:

```
 private int currentPageNo;
 public int CurrentPageNo
 {
    get { return currentPageNo; }
    set { currentPageNo = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPageNo"); }
 }
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
 {
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }

private void gotoPrevious(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ this.currentPageNo--;}

private void gotoPrevious(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ this.currentPageNo++;}
```

currentPageNo is changed when I press either the next page button or the previous page button, but this doesn't reflect in the UI.

It works when I do this.

```
private int currentPageNo;
 public int CurrentPageNo
 {
    get { return currentPageNo; }
    set { currentPageNo = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("currentPageNo"); }
 }
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
 {
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }

private void gotoPrevious(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
  this.currentPageNo--;
  NotifyPropertyChanged("currentPageNo");
}

private void gotoPrevious(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
  this.currentPageNo++;
  NotifyPropertyChanged("currentPageNo");
}
```

I have to notify from all the places wherever I am changing the value. This doesn't feel right. am I missing something? or it is meant to be done the second way?

Comment: Use `this.CurrentPageNo` instead, currently you're just editing the field, not the property i.e `NotifyPropertyChanged` won't be called.

Comment: @imsmn if I have to use CurrentPageNo (public int) for manipulation in code-behind then what is the use of currentPageNo (private int)? ```public int CurrentPageNo
 {   get { return currentPageNo; }    set { currentPageNo = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPageNo"); }
 }```  doesn't this thing connect "currentPageNo" & "CurrentPageNo"? or are you trying to say that I have to use "this.currentPageNo++" instead of "currentPageNo++"?

Comment: WPF Binding only works with [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) (that's what the public int thing is called). [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) is just a keyword. `NotifyPropertyChanged` is only called in the setter of your property, you surely have noticed that while debugging. That's why it's currently not working: You're not calling your property.

Comment: You should understand your language before starting WPF. At least know the basics. Otherwise you won't get far. C# is a magnitude simpler to learn than WPF. You definitely have to change the way you learn if you want to be successful. C# has properties and fields. Right now you are referencing a field - the backing field of the property. In order to execute the set() and get() of the property you must reference the property. I highly recommend to learn the basics starting with [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties).

Comment: There is only one function for your currentPageNo field - to store the value of the property.
And nowhere, except for the body of its property, you should not refer to this field.
I advise you to somehow mark such fields in the name.
I do this by naming it from the Low Line(`_`) and apply it only to fields that store property values.
Thus, I significantly reduce the likelihood of an accidental error.

Answer (score 3):

You have to notify about a change of the property by using the name of property, not the name of its backing field.

Then you should also increment and decrement the property, not the field.

```
private int currentPageNo;

public int CurrentPageNo
{
   get { return currentPageNo; }
   set
   {
       currentPageNo = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPageNo)); // property name
   }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

private void GotoPrevious(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    CurrentPageNo--; // set the property
}

private void GotoPrevious(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    CurrentPageNo++; // set the property
}
```

An alternative implementation without a backing field could look like shown below. The property setter is private to make sure that only the owning class can set the property. It must then always fire the PropertyChanged event.

```
public int CurrentPageNo { get; private set; }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

private void GotoPrevious(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    CurrentPageNo--;
    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPageNo));
}

private void GotoPrevious(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    CurrentPageNo++;
    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPageNo));
}
```